# Partitioning techniques for finding large matrix determinents

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, integer-partitions

I'm in a linear algebra class and we're doing determinants right now. I got this matrix to do:

$\begin{matrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}$

It wouldn't be hard to solve via row reduction but I hate to see so many 0s in such a near symetric form go to waste... I had problems close to the one I posted above where I figured out through googling about shcurs, which is convenient if you can cancel the ugly term! This one doesn't have the proper 0 positioning for that though, although it's very close. What's a nice way to solve this without rowreduction?

Comment: Do you know about Laplace's formula? If yes, start with the first row, giving you 2 $4\times 4$-Determinants with lots of $0$'s and proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one isn't going to be very friendly, but aside from row-reduction (really the best method) a not-too-terrible way to proceed would be as follows:

Start by [cofactor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix) along the first row, so that

$$\left|\begin{matrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|=2\cdot\left|\begin{matrix} -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|-1\cdot\left|\begin{matrix} 3 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|$$ The second $4\times 4$ cofactor matrix is very friendly, and we find that $$\begin{align}\left|\begin{matrix} 3 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right| &= 3\cdot\left|\begin{matrix}1 & -1 & 2 \\ -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|\\ &= 3\cdot\bigl(6+0+6-0-9-(-4)\bigr)\\ &=3\cdot 7\\ &= 21,\end{align}$$ using the [general formula for determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#3.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A03_matrices), so that $$\left|\begin{matrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|=2\cdot\left|\begin{matrix} -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|-21.$$ The first $4\times 4$ cofactor isn't as nice, but again using cofactor expansion along the first row, we have $$\begin{align}\left|\begin{matrix} -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right| &= -1\cdot\left|\begin{matrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|-2\left|\begin{matrix} 4 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|\\ &= -1\cdot7-2\cdot 4\cdot\left|\begin{matrix} 2 & 4 \\ -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|\\ &= -7-2\cdot 4\cdot\bigl((2)(3)-(4)(-1)\bigr)\\ &=-7-80\\ &=-87,\end{align}$$ so $$\left|\begin{matrix} 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & -3 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right|=2\cdot-87-21=-174-21=-195.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you use expansion by minors (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminantExpansionbyMinors.html) you can get the solution (det=-195) very rapidly.

Comment: I was hoping something prettier existed